# Rally Excel Add-In

Tags: excel, rally

I am attempting to run a query in Rally Addin for Excel but am getting a ambiguous error, no idea how to resolve, can you assist?
This is the query:

```
((((State != Closed) AND (CreationDate <= 2015-02-10)) AND ((Severity = Crash/Data Loss) OR (Severity = Major Problem))) AND (Iteration != Iteration 34))
```

The error is:

> Could not parse:  Error parsing expression -- expected ")" but saw
>   "Loss" instead.

Comment: Is "Crash/Data Loss" supposed to be in quotes?

Comment: Hi Joel, yes both the severity types needed to be in quotes. Once I resolved that I was getting another error on the iteration part of the query.  it needed to be reworded as iteration.name = "iteration 34".

Answer (score 1):

As you confirmed in a comment, you just need some quotes, ie

```
((((State != Closed) AND (CreationDate <= 2015-02-10)) AND 
((Severity = "Crash/Data Loss") OR (Severity = "Major Problem"))) AND 
(Iteration != "Iteration 34"))
```

Comment: Also, the interation needed to be adjusted from                               Iteration != "Iteration 34"))         to        iteration.name !="iteration 34"